# What is the difference between building an iphone app in Xcode and reopening it on the iphone? Wh

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My application brings up a different view each time it is built in Xcode. This is exactly what I want it to do. However, if I simply press the back to menu button in the simulator and then reopen it the view does not change. I am changing the view by overwriting the viewDidLoad function in a Custom View Controller. Why is it that ViewDidLoad is not called every time I click on the icon? Will that mean that on a real iphone it also will not be?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

When you press the menu button in the simulator (or the actual iPhone) the OS, basically, stops running your app.  However, it doesn't necessarily terminate the app; if you reopen the app before the OS has decided to terminate it, you will find yourself in the same state you were before.  Since the app isn't reloaded, viewDidLoad isn't called.

However, viewWillAppear should still be called each time, I believe, and this might be a better place to put your code that changes how things look. **Edit:** A quick test shows that this isn't the case.  I'll poke around and see if I can find another notification mechanism.

Comment: Ah, got it: you can register to receive UIApplicationDidEnterBackground and UIApplicationWillEnterForeground notifications.